# React build error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useEffect')

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, azure-devops

I'm currently building an azure DevOps plugin following [the example project](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-extension-sample/blob/master/src/Common.tsx)

In the file Common.tsx im implementing the useEffect hook:

```
export function showRootComponent(component: React.ReactElement<any>) {
  const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
  let baseUrl = '';

  React.useEffect(() => {
    SDK.init();
    const initializeState = async () => {
     ....
    };
    initializeState();
  }, []);

  ReactDOM.render(
    <SettingContext.Provider value={{ baseUrl: baseUrl }}>
      {component}
    </SettingContext.Provider>,
    rootElement,
  );
}
```

When im building this extension and try it in Azure Devops I get the error:

```
ResultsHub.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useEffect')
```

Do I need to add changes to the Webpack config? Maybe the react components can't resolved?

Comment: You've got multiple versions of react issue.